# SQL LEFT JOIN with two conditions in one table

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I have a query like this (explanation below):

```
SELECT
    c.customer_name, 
    c.customer_email, 
    c.customer_tel, 
    a.address_1, 
    a.address_2, 
    a.postcode 
FROM 
    customer c 
LEFT JOIN 
    address a ON c.customer_id = a.customer_id 
WHERE 
    c.customer_type = 'R' 
    AND c.customer_id = 25
```

The address table can hold the the same `customer_id` twice e.g. 25 but with the `customer_type` column either `G` or `R` makes it unique.

I want to return only the address from the address table where `customer_id` is the same in both tables and the `customer_type` must be `R`.

Right now it is returning the match of `customer_id` ignoring `customer_type`.

How do I ensure customer tables values always return but address fields return only if the condition (`customer_type`) matches?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: `customer_type` belongs to `customer` or `address`? Your query says the opposite of your explanation.

Comment: They belong in both tables, below answer solves it.

Comment: Put the required predicate in the `on` of the `join`. Each row pair for which the predicate evaluates to `true` will be joined, others will not. `left join` includes all the rows from left table regardless of the predicate in `on`.

Comment: @Abu Nooh: Ah, so you have a composite key. A customer is uniquely identified by the combination of customer_id and customer_type in both tables. Then both columns should be in the `ON` clause: `ON c.customer_id = a.customer_id AND c.customer_type = a.customer_type`. And are you sure you want an outer join? Do you want to show customers that have no address? And why do you have two tables with the same key (customer_id + customer_type)?

Comment: It was the best way I could think of to allow registration and guest checkout but have address optionally.

Comment: @astentx yes that's what was missing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  c.customer_name, 
  c.customer_email, 
  c.customer_tel, 
  a.address_1, 
  a.address_2, 
  a.postcode 
FROM 
  customer c 
  LEFT JOIN address a 
  ON c.customer_id = a.customer_id AND customer_type ='R'
WHERE 
  c.customer_type = 'R' 
    AND c.customer_id = 25
```

This will work on MSSQL queries.

Comment: This works! Just needed the `AND customer_type ='R'` before the WHERE. Thank you